# Bizarre font rendering in Chrome UI (address bar) in Windows

Tags: windows, google-chrome, fonts

My friend's laptop is displaying text really weird in Chrome. Elsewhere on the computer it looks fine. Internet Explorer (and other browsers) render text just fine.

With a completely fresh install of chrome, this is a glance at what is happening:

[image]

Any suggestions what might cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the default font set has been replaced.

Go to [chrome://settings/fonts](http://chrome://settings/fonts) and replace the values there with my values(i.e Default values for Windows 7)

[image: fonts in chrome]

Comment: thanks for that. sorry I didn't notice this response earlier. Haven't had access to this computer in a long time :)